# How to move Ubuntu "/" from SSD to HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have a dual boot system (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04) on my ASUS laptop. It has a 1TB HDD and a 128GB SSD. Currently, the partition table looks like this:

```
**1TB HDD**
Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048 1646321663 1646319616   785G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2  1646323712 1953523711  307200000 146.5G Linux filesystem (HOME)

*128GB SDD*
Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048    534527    532480  260M EFI System
/dev/sdb2     534528    567295     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3     567296 166406798 165839503 79.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  248328192 250068991   1740800  850M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb5  166408192 248328191  81920000 39.1G Linux filesystem (ROOT)
```

I need more room for my Windows OS (on SSD), so I want to move my Ubuntu ROOT partition to the HDD. What is the safest way to do this? I'm assuming I will need to shrink `/dev/sda1` and create a new partition for "/". But I'm not sure on the best way to migrate it over.

Comment: Possible reference to moving your ~/ (home) folder to another place: https://www.howtogeek.com/442101/how-to-move-your-linux-home-directory-to-another-hard-drive/ or this one: maketecheasier

Comment: @Graham This is about moving the home folder. I need to move “/“. This says i can move my home folder and reinstall Linux. I don’t want to re install it because I have so many custom settings and configurations.

Comment: Is sda also gpt as sdb has to be for Windows UEFI boot. Almost all your settings are in /home. Possibly some system settings in /etc. (I edit grub). And export of list of installed apps. That is your normal backup which you have, so when (not if) drive fails you do not lose everything. So then easy to reinstall & restore from backup. Be sure to mount but NOT check format of /home during install.

Comment: Please consider that making partition changes is the easiest way to lose entire filesystems with a moment's mistake. Therefor, please back up everything to an external external drive or the cloud, and verify the backup matches the source files; then, backup again to a different external drive or a different cloud destination and verify those files match the source. Only then should you proceed.

Comment: Does anyone have a tutorial or guide on how to move "/" to another partition?